# How to set tabindex for angular material elements?

Tags: angular, tabindex

How could I set `tabindex=-1` on angular material elements?
f.e. if I set it into mat-checkbox, in DOM I see:

```
mat-checkbox tab-index=-1
   label
      input tabindex=0
```

and in the `mat-button-toggle` the same: button inside `mat-wrappera` doesn't change its tab index.

Comment: it's hard to help without any reproducible example. Can you make a stackblitz or something for us to test against? [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think you XY problem. What are you trying to achieve that you need set tabindex?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

By the time there is no way to do so.
You may follow up here:
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/12041

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind the `tabindex` attribute of the **Angular Material** element, you should assign the value after rendering the element.

To make it clear, I created 2 `mat-select` elements and 2 properties to bind to `tabindex` attribute.

First property (`tabindex_1`) will be declared and assigned normally, the second one (`tabindex_2`) will be assigned inside `ngAfterViewInit` method.

If you open the console, you will see the element that binds `tabindex_1` returned back to 0, but the second one is binded as expected.

**app.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Gender</mat-label>
  <mat-select [tabindex]="tabindex_1">
    <mat-option>Male</mat-option>
    <mat-option>Female</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Country</mat-label>
  <mat-select [tabindex]="tabindex_2">
    <mat-option>US</mat-option>
    <mat-option>UK</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  // this will be ignored
  tabindex_1 = '1';
  tabindex_2;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // this will be reflected
    this.tabindex_2 = '2';
  }
}
```

Check this example at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v6c6w8?file=src/app/app.component.ts)